# Erro de sintaxe PHP na inserção de uma imagem

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou a inserir uma imagem na base de dados com o seguinte código

```
$nome_img = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "images/Produtos/".$nome_img){
   $query=  "INSERT INTO produtos(ImagemProduto) VALUES ('$nome_img'))";
}else{
   echo "Erro!";
}
```

**E está-me a dar o seguinte erro:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\user\functions.php on line 218

A linha 218 é a da query

```
$query=  "INSERT INTO produtos(ImagemProduto) VALUES ('$nome_img')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, aparentemente está correcto, mas para dar erro, provavelmente está relacionado com os `"` e os `'`.

Eu tentava escrever de novo a linha, sem copiar/colar, podes até tentar usar uma forma diferente de [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790501/php-variable-interpolation-vs-concatenation), assim

`$query = "INSERT INTO produtos(ImagemProduto) VALUES ('" . $nome_img . "')";`

ou

`$query = "INSERT INTO produtos(ImagemProduto) VALUES ('{$nome_img}')";`

**EDIT**

O problema na verdade está na falta do `)` do `if` logo acima da linha onde a variável `$query` é definida.

Mais, também precisas adicionar a instrução para correr a query na base de dados, logo na linha seguinte onde estás a definir a variável `$query`.

`$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);`

Comment: mesmo a escrever ambas as linhas de código à mão dá erro

Comment: O problema está no `if`. Falta um `)` antes de abrir a chaveta `{`.

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "images/Produtos/".$nome_img) ) {`

Comment: isso resolveu o erro , agora não está é a registar

Comment: Está a retornar "Erro!"?

Comment: Tens de executar a query SQL na base de dados.
Podes usar `mysqli_query($query);` logo depois de definires a variável `$query`.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Olá amigo. antes de tudo corrigi isso aqui: produtos(ImagemProduto). Separa produtos do parêntese produtos (ImagemProduto). Vê se ajuda, caso não talvez seja na questão do insert do mysqli.

Comment: @DávilAndré não era disso continua a dar erro na mesma ao inserir a imagem

Comment: @JoséGomes alterei a resposta para dar mais alguma informação. Acho que o problema que tens agora é que não estás ligado a um banco de dados. Coloquei uns links para documentação que te deve dar uma ajuda.

Comment: @JoséGomes o problema agora é o caminho de destino do `move_uploaded_file` estar incorrecto ou a pasta não ter as permissões certas.

Comment: o caminho está certo

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro é na linha do upload:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "images/Produtos/".$nome_img){
```

Esta faltando um `)`, deveria ser:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "images/Produtos/".$nome_img)){
```

Comment: Era. Actualmente falta executar a query :)

Comment: @Leite tua pergunta não tem código de execução de query, não tem PDO não tem mysqli, é impossivel ajudar sem saber como é o código, só tem uma string em uma variavel dentro da if se puder mostrar o código eu poderei ajuda.

Comment: esse parênteses já foi colocado e continua a dar a mensagem "Erro!". ou seja não esta a fazer o upload da imagem

Comment: Não é minha a pergunta. Estava só a indicar que o problema já é outro.

Comment: @Leite o titulo da pergunta e a descrição da pergunta só falam de erro de sintaxe, esta respondido ao que foi perguntando, não foi informado em local algum da pergunta dificuldade sobre a execução das APIs para acessar banco de dados, a pergunta é sobre erro de sintaxe, é complicado responder a algo que não tem código para sabermos aonde falhou.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, concordo.

Comment: @JoséGomes então podem ser 3 erros, 1. ou a pasta `images/Produtos/` não existe 2. a pasta `images/Produtos/` é inacessível, 3. esta usando linux server e por isto a arquivos e pastas tem nomes case-sensitive, e você digitou o nome errado.